# Quick Reference in Two Columns

Tags: alignment

Pramod Achar's book on perverse sheaves has a quick reference in the back that looks like this. How can I achieve something similar? The important things to me are: the general spacing (although maybe I would enjoy less margins on the outside), the two columns, the numbering and labeling, the horizontal line separators. For language, I only care about English. I don't have any font preference.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: There are dozens of formatting decisions embedded in the screenshot you posted. E.g., font family, font size, column width, column height, page width, page height, interline spacing, language customization (`babel`?), numbering style of sections, numbering style of theorem-like environments, styling of itemize-like environments, thickness of the lines that span the width of a column, etc. Which formatting are important to you? And which ones are not important? Please be specific.

Comment: @Mico You are right ... The important things to me are: the general spacing (although maybe I would enjoy less margins on the outside), the two columns, the numbering and labeling, the horizontal line separators. For language, I only care about English. I don't have any font preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to approach your problem:

- Part 1: write text as usual, using `\section` and `\subsection`
- Part 2: use `\twocolumn` AND replace sections by own commands `\qrs` and `\qrsub`
- Part 3: same as Part 2, but using `\onecolumn` AND `package multicol`

See also this remark in the code below, after having finished Part 1:

[image: remark]

The most interesting part here may be at the beginning: the definition and use of counters and own commands.

Defining counters and initializing them to 0 is simple:

```
\newcounter{cqr}%       counting "sections"
\setcounter{cqr}{0}
\newcounter{csqr}%      counting "subsections"
\setcounter{csqr}{0}
```

Replacing `\section` can be done e.g. via, where `\thecqr` returns the value of counter `cqr`, and the rest is just typesetting as you want it, with `#1` holding the title you'll pass:

```
\newcommand\qrs[1]{%    acting as "section"
    \stepcounter{cqr}%  increment "section"-number
    \setcounter{csqr}{0}%
    \begin{center}%
        \textbf{QR\thecqr. #1}%
    \end{center}%
}
```

Note that the counter for the "subsections" replacement is initialized when incrementing the "section". Now the subsection replacement looks quite similar, but with slightly different typesetting:

```
\newcommand\qrsub[1]{%  acting as "subsection"
    \stepcounter{csqr}%
    \begin{flushleft}%
        \hrule%
        \bigskip%
        \textbf{QR\thecqr.\thecsqr\ }(#1)%
    \end{flushleft}%
}
```

(P.S.: The many `%` are necessary.)

Personally I may favour the onecolumn/multicol approach over the twocolumn approach.

[image: results]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

% ~~~ QR-"sections" and "subsections" ~~~
\newcounter{cqr}%       counting "sections"
\setcounter{cqr}{0}
\newcounter{csqr}%      counting "subsections"
\setcounter{csqr}{0}

\newcommand\qrs[1]{%    acting as "section"
    \stepcounter{cqr}%  increment "section"-number
    \setcounter{csqr}{0}%
    \begin{center}%
        \textbf{QR\thecqr. #1}%
    \end{center}%
}

\newcommand\qrsub[1]{%  acting as "subsection"
    \stepcounter{csqr}%
    \begin{flushleft}%
        \hrule
        \bigskip
        \textbf{QR\thecqr.\thecsqr\ }(#1)%
    \end{flushleft}%
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 Strategy: start small, refine later

% PART 1 
    % ------------------------------
    \section{Triangulated categories} 
     \subsection{Distinguished triangles}
     Write some math-text here, like $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, which you can also list as:
     
     \begin{itemize}
       \item case 1: $c^2 \in R$
       \item case 2: $c^2 \in C$
     \end{itemize}
     
     \subsection{Canonical functions}
      Same as above. $E = m c^2$. Same as above. Same as above. $E = h \nu$. Same as above. 
    
    % ------------------------------
    \section{Sheaves}
     \lipsum[4]
     \subsection{The six operations}
     Same as above.

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\bigskip 
\fbox{Now let's try some things:}

\begin{itemize}
  \item using twocolumn and setting columnwidth
  \item using self-defined qrs to replace sections and counter cqr
  \item using self-defined qrsub to replace subsections and counter csqr
  \item use onecolumn and package multicol
\end{itemize}

 
% ~~~ now let's copy and introduce changes ~~~~~
% PART 2 
\twocolumn[\begin{center}%
\huge{\textbf{Quick reference}}%
\end{center}]%          starts a new page in two columns
\setlength{\columnwidth}{4cm}

    % ------------------------------
    \qrs{Triangulated categories} 
     \qrsub{Distinguished triangles}
     Write some math-text here, like $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, which 
     you can also list as:
     
     \begin{itemize}
       \item case 1: $c^2 \in R$
       \item case 2: $c^2 \in C$
     \end{itemize}
     
     \qrsub{Canonical functions}
      Same as above. $E = m c^2$. Same as above. Same as 
      above. $E = h \nu$. Same as above. 
    
    % ------------------------------
    \qrs{Sheaves}
     \lipsum[4]
     \qrsub{The six operations}
     Same as above.
    
    To fill the rest of the page:
    \lipsum[1-2]


% ~~~ now let's use onecolumn and multicol ~~~~~
% PART 3 
\onecolumn%             starts a new page in one column

\begin{center}%
\huge{\textbf{Quick reference}}%
\end{center}
\vspace{5mm}

\setcounter{cqr}{0}%            resetting the QR-counter
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % ------------------------------
    \qrs{Triangulated categories} 
     \qrsub{Distinguished triangles}
     Write some math-text here, like $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, 
     which you can also list as:
     
     \begin{itemize}
       \item case 1: $c^2 \in R$
       \item case 2: $c^2 \in C$
     \end{itemize}
     
     \qrsub{Canonical functions}
      Same as above. $E = m c^2$. Same as above. 
      Same as above. $E = h \nu$. Same as above. 
    
    % ------------------------------
    \qrs{Sheaves}
     \lipsum[4]
     \qrsub{The six operations}
     Same as above.
    
    To fill the rest of the page:
    \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really great, thanks!

Comment: Thank you  // Latex is quite flexible, the more you learn and try. Often there are many ways to do it.